# why it is showing error i.e. __init()__ takes 1 position argument but 2 were given when i'm passing url in get method of requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, request, http-post, get-request

I'm trying to use get method of requests module but it is not working. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.python.org')
print(r.status_code)
```

**Here is my error:**

```
$ python request_testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "request_testing.py", line 4, in <module>
    get('http://www.python.org')
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 412, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 315, in get_connection
    conn = self.poolmanager.connection_from_url(url)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 298, in connection_from_url
    return self.connection_from_host(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 245, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 260, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 281, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 213, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 197, in __init__
    self.pool = self.QueueCls(maxsize)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: What are the version numbers of `requests` and `urllib3`?

Comment: 2.25.1 and 1.26.2 respectively

Comment: That's strange. On my machine your code with the same library versions runs for me without any problems. Only difference: I'm still using Python 3.7.

Comment: so now what should I do